# Jupyter notebook unable to see anything in browser

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

For weeks I was able to start up the notebook in the Chrome browser. Now every time I start the notebook the page is completely blank, and when inspecting the console I get the error shown in the image below. I have no clue how to resolve this problem and so any help would be appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you're running jupyter via `jupyter notebook` in a terminal, what does that output? That's going to be much more helpful for debugging than the browser screenshot.

Comment: Yes that's a good idea, I have now added a screenshot of the terminal output.